# Trying to know how many rows I have from the different fleets in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm working with a project that has 3 models.

- Devices: All the devices involved in the project.
- Fleets: Each device is in one fleet.
- Data: The data that the devices send.

Now I want to know how much data have come me today.

In my view I have this,

```
def dataPlots(request):
    today = datetime.date(2020, 5, 18)
    data = DevData.objects.filter(data_timestamp__date=today)
    data  = loads(serializers.serialize('json', data))
```

If I use `len()` I can now the total value. But how can I know how much data do I have for each fleet?

I have come to create this loop that would tell me for each device, but what I need is the value for each fleet and furthermore I think I am getting complicated.

```
data_dict = {}
for d in data:
    if d['fields']['dev_eui'] in data_dict:
        data_dict[d['fields']['dev_eui']] = data_dict[d['fields']['dev_eui']] + 1
    else:
        data_dict[d['fields']['dev_eui']] = 1

print(data_dict)
```

The models are:

```
class Fleet(models.Model):
    fleet_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    fleet_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

class Device(models.Model):
    dev_eui = models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    dev_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    fleet_id = models.ForeignKey(Fleet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dev_eui

class DevData(models.Model):
    data_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid1, editable=False)
    data_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    data = models.FloatField()

    dev_eui = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dev_eui
```

Can somebody help me? I imagine that combining two models and some filter should suffice, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the `Fleet`s with the given amount of data, for example:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Fleet.objects.filter(
    device__devdata__data_timestamp__date=today
).annotate(
    total_data=Count('device__devdata')
)
```

The `Fleet` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.total_data` that contains the total amount of data for `today`.

Comment: mmm I'm not sure how to use this. If I just put this and save it in a variable I will have the count?

Comment: If I just save your code, I have the active fleets today, but not how many rows/data I have

Comment: @Lleims: you have, what if you iterate over the fleets, and print `fleet.total_data` for each fleet?

Comment: As said before, it adds an extra attribute to the model objects.